# Формула суммирования по условиям в Google-таблицах, в Excel

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, excel-формулы

=iferror(SUMIFS('Лист1'!C:C;'Лист1'!B:B;"MONTH=12");0)

Мне нужно, чтобы из списка операций на Листе1, суммировался диапазон Ячеек B, где подходит месяц. К примеру мне нужно сделат отчет в таблице по месяцам.

Answer (score 1):

*СУММЕСЛИ, СУММЕСЛИМН* работают с прямыми ссылками на диапазоны, указать условие на диапазон в этих функциях не получится. Но можно задать два условия:

*>=начало_месяца, <= конец_месяца*

```
=СУММЕСЛИМН(C:C;B:B;">=01.12.17";B:B;"<=31.12.17")
```

Со ссылками на ячейки:

```
=СУММЕСЛИМН(C:C;B:B;">="&A1;B:B;"<="&A2)
```

Можно заменить другой функцией:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(C2:C10;--(B2:B10>=A1);--(B2:B10<=A2))
```

Но *СУММПРОИЗВ* в данном случае хуже: работает медленнее; нужно указывать конкретные диапазоны в столбцах - эта функция, в отличие от *СУММЕСЛИМН*, не умеет определять пользовательский диапазон и будет просчитывать весь столбец.

Применение *ЕСЛИОШИБКА* здесь неоправдано.

Формулы написаны для применения в *Excel*, для *Google*-таблиц нужно перевести названия функций.